# Map returning an empty array when fetching local JSON file

Tags: javascript, fetch

This is my first time attempting to fetch a local JSON file.

I've gotten the data into an array called "drinks"  when I console log the array I can see all of the data from the JSON file, but when I try to use a higher order function it'll return an empty array.  I'm doing this on my local live server, but I've also tried with the web server for chrome, I haven't noticed a difference.

```
let drinks=[];

fetch('./coldMenu.JSON', {
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
   }
})
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>drinks.push(...data.drinks))

    console.log(drinks)

   let coldMenuHtml= drinks.map(drink=>{
       ` <img src="${drink.img}" alt="${drink.drink}" class="im">`
    });

    console.log(coldMenuHtml)
```

The goal is to get the information from the JSON and use it to create a coffee menu. Before the menu is displayed there will be a box asking if they want to see the menu for hot or cold beverages, then I planned to fetch and put the information onto the page.

Comment: well you should be seeing an empty array when you do a `console.log`

Comment: I've tried inserting into a div by setting the divs innerHTML= coldMenuHtml, that's not working either...

Comment: that's because `coldMenuHtml` is an array of `undefined` and that's not how you append the `html`. better look at my answer below for details

Answer (score 0):

The fetch is async which is why data wont be available right after the last then.
Add the logic inside the last then

To test

```
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)

    let coldMenuHtml= data.drinks.map(drink => {
     `<img src="${drink.img}" alt="${drink.drink}" class="im">`
    });

    console.log(coldMenuHtml)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop on the data before it's available. The universal issue of most newbies when making async calls in `JS` so you better read this [`How to return response from an async call`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Now the second issue is, you are generating the `html` inside a map and not returning anything so you'll get an array of `undefined`. And that'll do nothing.

It would be easier if you just consider using a simple for loop to generate the `html` and keep appending to the `div` you want

For your code to fix it. Just move the code inside the last `.then` and it should work.

Something like

```
let drinks = [];

fetch('./coldMenu.JSON', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        drinks = [...data.drinks];

        console.log(drinks)

        for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
            document.querySelector('selector').innerHTML += `<img src="${drinks[i].img}" alt="${drinks[i].drink}" class="im">`
        }


    })
```